# Tomcat with tomcat pool missing DataSource entry in JMX

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jmx

I have a DataSource configured a tomcat instance in the server.xml like

```
<Resource name="MyDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          maxTotal="50" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="10000"
          testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
          username="username" password="password" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//database.whatever.com:1521/mydb"/>
```

But this doesn't show up in JMX under Catalina>DataSource

If I use DBCP2 (org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory) it shows up fine.

I see there's a jmxEnabled option but that doesn't seem to affect and also the default value is true anyway. Am I missing something?